# Python Urllib ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib3, pyelasticsearch

Till Oct 20, it was fine. Oct 21, it failed with the below messages. Can any one help here

```
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-i8sl36tr/elasticsearch-curator/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-i8sl36tr/elasticsearch-curator/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-et0c4kgw
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-i8sl36tr/elasticsearch-curator/
    Complete output (20 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-i8sl36tr/elasticsearch-curator/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'
```

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-i8sl36tr/elasticsearch-curator/setup.py", line 177, in <module>
        tests_require = ["mock", "nose", "coverage", "nosexcover"]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 676, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 775, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.24.3 (/tmp/pip-install-i8sl36tr/elasticsearch-curator/.eggs/urllib3-1.24.3-py3.7.egg), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.26,>=1.25.4'), {'botocore'})
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 19.10.2020 AWS released new botocore version 1.19.0.
So far versions 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2 are not compatible with elasticsearch-curator - version 5.8.1.
I had same problem and temporary fixed issue by installing older version of elasticsearch-curator - version 5.6.0.
I believe AWS will soon release botocore version that is compatible with elasticsearch-curator - version 5.8.1.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Wyci, it helped me. I'm downgrading the package :)

Comment: Why do you feel that AWS would release a new feature of Botocore?  They have been clear that they are pulling requests out of it for a while.  SHoudln't it be that ElasticSearch-curator should release a new version that works with botocore?

Comment: Yes, you are right. ElasticSearch-curator should release a new version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Python environment is inconsistent with the versions requires by your packages. Have you tried installing your environment with the [`--use-feature=2020-resolver`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020) flag?

```
python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver elasticsearch elasticsearch-curator ...
```

Comment: Yes @sethmlarson, it helped to know the cause of the issue. And with this, I get to know the next series of dependency conflicts as well. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly saying, I discovered another 4 sets of conflict packages which are about to explode, Thanks again.